# Доступ к родительскому блоку через CSS

Tags: css

Как написать селектор в CSS, чтобы по наведению мыши на дочерний блок (bar) менялись свойства родительского (foo):

```
<div id='foo'>
  <div id='bar'></div>
</div>
```

Скажем, чтоб менялся фоновый цвет?

Comment: Похоже, что опять решения на чистом CSS нет :(

Comment: [Selectors][1]


  [1]: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, каскад стилей применяется сверху вниз по дереву, максимум как высоко можно добраться - до элементов на одном уровне с "matched element".

Answer (score 1):

Низя навести на bar, не наведя foo, через ксс.